# UILocalnotification not getting alert on set time?

Tags: iphone

I did this for getting alert on set time. But it's not alerting on time. I am setting time from datepicker. How I can solved this problem?

```
- (void)scheduleNotificationWithInterval:(int)minutesBefore {

      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

      UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
      if (localNotif == nil)
          return;
      NSLog(@"Date %@",datePicker.date);
      localNotif.fireDate = datePicker.date;
      localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
      if ([freq isEqualToString:@"Daily"]) {
          localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
      }

      localNotif.alertBody = @"Radio Asia Alarm";
      localNotif.alertAction = @"Ok";

      localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

      NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Radio Asia Alarm" forKey:@"Message"];
      localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
      [localNotif release];
}
```

Also I call this method where I click button after set time and date

```
  [self scheduleNotificationWithInterval:1];
```

I am not getting alert. What I can do?

Comment: check the date format of datePicker.date string

Comment: Try to log firedate agter you set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are setting the right timezone? Im sure the problem could be there

Have you tried without setting it?